# Segmentation fault google assistant sdk

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I was trying to install the google assistant on my raspberry pi. I was trying to run the sample code but it says segmentation fault. What on earth does it mean and what can I do? And do me a favor and answer in simple terms.

Thanks in advance!
Adhish Nirej paul

Comment: I've had a [similar problem](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-python-client-v2/issues/45) with the Dialogflow Python client library. You might want to open a bug report if you can reproduce the issue.

Comment: can you confirm which version of the google-assistant-library you're using and on which platform? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with Ubuntu running Spyder. At that time, the problem was with `PyQt5` and `pyopengl`. Library dependencies.

In my Raspberry Pi I installed Google Assistant following this sequence and it runs smoothly:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-venv
sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev libmpg123-dev
pip install imageio
python -m pip install google-assistant-library==1.0.1
python -m pip install google-assistant-sdk[samples]==0.5.1
pip3 install google-auth
python -m pip install google-auth-oauthlib[tool]
pip install google-assistant-grpc
```

Try to run the code with "-v" to see eventual log of errors.